# Поиск библиотеки для рендера

Tags: python, библиотеки, render, моделирование

Добрый день, StackOverflow

Я достаточно долго пытаюсь найти нужную библиотеку для моей модели, но увы, безуспешно. Поэтому прошу помощи.
У меня есть кинетическая модель (написана на Python), которая моделирует поведение молекул (по факту — сферы) в пространстве и во времени. То есть через определенный промежуток времени происходит изменение их расположения, могут добавиться новые сферы или исчезнуть старые.
Что именно мне нужно:

- создавать 3D модель одного состояния системы на экране и возможность её "крутить" мышкой (клавиатурой)
- сохранять "снимок" текущего состояния в jpg-файл с одного какого-либо ракурса (чтобы в дальнейшем сделать из полученного множества файлов полноценное видео)
- перейти к следующему состоянию, то есть изменить положение сфер, добавить новые или удалить старые. Здесь есть вариант удалять все сферы и заполнять их заново для следующего состояния, но на самом деле это будет медленнее, чем работа с каждой сферой из предыдущего состояния по-отдельности

Желательно:

- создавать анимацию процесса (то есть по сути то же видео) с определенным промежутком времени и возможность так же "крутить" эту модель в процессе
- сохранять это "видео" в файл

Несмотря на то, что модель написана на Python, на выходе я получаю текстовые файлы с матрицами-состояниями и могу их обрабатывать в любом другом языке (работал с C++, Java).

Пробовал работать в Blender, но не нашел там возможности перехода от одного состояния к другому средствами скрипта.
Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, подходящую для меня библиотеку.

Comment: А каков примерный порядок количества этих сфер? 10? 1000? миллионы?

Comment: @crantisz сотни, меньше 1000.

Comment: а в чем проблема возникла в Blender? Можно спокойно сделать анимацию посредством [keyframe_insert](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_60_6/bpy.types.bpy_struct.html#bpy.types.bpy_struct.keyframe_insert) (можно анимировать как видимость объекта, так и его местоположение).

Comment: @crantisz вот скажем, я расположил 2 сферы. Следующее состояние — первая сфера изменяет свое положение, а другая — исчезает. Я пытался (без скрипта, руками) создать в первом фрейме две сферы, дальше переключался на второй фрейм, удалял сферу, а она исчезала и с первого фрейма тоже.

Comment: Естественно, вы удалили объект, вместе с анимацией и со всеми данными. Вместо этого надо анимировать видимость объекта, для рендера

Comment: @crantisz по факту мне даже не нужно анимировать плавность, просто последовательность кадров хотелось бы сделать и вывести либо целиком всю последовательность в видео-файл (насколько я понимаю, нужно ставить камеру и рендерить), либо каждое состояние выводить в соответствующий файл-картинку. Можно попросить у Вас пример кода, пожалуйста?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56112/discussion-between-cheremushkin-and-crantisz).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример скрипта на python.

скрывает выделенный объект (в превью `hide` и на рендере `hide_render`) на 10 кадре анимации:

```
import bpy

ob = bpy.context.active_object

bpy.context.scene.frame_set(0)
ob.hide_render = False
ob.hide = False
ob.keyframe_insert(data_path="hide_render")
ob.keyframe_insert(data_path="hide")

bpy.context.scene.frame_set(10)
ob.hide_render = True
ob.hide = True
ob.keyframe_insert(data_path="hide_render")
ob.keyframe_insert(data_path="hide")
```